# Display Dedicated IP into clientareainvoices.tpl list in WHMCS?

Tags: hook, invoice, whmcs

I'm using WHMCS 8.x and Smarty PHP is already enabled.

I hope to use some code or hook function to let the **dedicated ip** or **hostname** to display on the page **clientareainvoices.tpl** (**/clientarea.php?action=invoices**) list .
I hope anyone can help me with this  .
Thanks alot .

I have search a lot of plan , but all not working . I don't know whether this can be done with hook .

Hope someone of genius can help me about this .

the function like this in the picture .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0l7B7.png)
thanks thanks  thanks.

I tried to use a hook file to do this . and tried to connect the database tables use left join . like :
the file is like :

```html
select * from tblinvoices t1 
left join tblinvoiceitems t2 on t1.id=t2.invoiceid
left join tblhosting t3 on t2.relid=t3.id
WHERE t3.dedicatedIP = value
```

And I add this into the hook file .

```html
<?php

if (!defined("WHMCS")) {
    die("This file cannot be accessed directly");
}

use WHMCS\Database\Capsule as DB;

add_hook('ClientAreaPageInvoices', 1, function($vars) {
    
    $invoices = DB::table('tblinvoices')->where('invoicenum', $vars['invoicenum'])->get();

        $fieldId = 'invoicenum';
        $csVals = [];
        foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
            $fieldVal = '';
            $data = DB::table('tblinvoices AS t1')
            ->leftJoin('tblinvoiceitems AS t2', 't1.invoicenum', '=', 't2.invoiceid')
            ->leftJoin('tblhosting AS t3', 't2.relid', '=', 't3.id')
            ->select('t3.domain')
            ->where('t1.invoicenum', $fieldId)->where('t3.domain', $invoice['invoicenum'])
            ->first();
            if (!is_null($data)) {
                $fieldVal = $data->value;
            }
            $csVals[$invoice['invoicenum']] = $fieldVal;
        }
        return ['domain' => $csVals];

});
```

But all not working for this . it shows a result "Array" , hope anybody can hlep me . thanks in advance .

Comment: I know I should creating a hook to pass the variable to .tpl and adjust the table code to present it, but I just don't know how to do it exactly . hope anyone can help .

Answer (score 0):

First you don't need to query invoices again, since the invoices are available in `$vars['invoices']` variable.

`$invoices = $vars['invoices'];`

The code should work, you just need to edit the file `clientareainvoices.tpl` in your active template and replace:

`<td>{$invoice.invoicenum}</td>` with

`<td>{$invoice.invoicenum} - {$domain[$invoice.invoicenum]}</td>`

Comment: thanks for reply , Wesamly . I have resolve this . the problem of this code is $data->value should be the domain table name .thanks.

Comment: @Ref Glad you solved your issue, and welcome :)